# Is there a problem with my gym routine?

Tags: exercise, workout-routines, calories, gym, routine

I try to go the gym every night, at about 10pm - 12pm.

Is it good to go at this time?

My aim is to become thinner, I am quite stocky, I have never been to the gym to increase muscle size, only to reduce my size, i.e. to get fitter/ thinner.

I normally do a straight half an hour on the rowing machine, buring around 300 - 340 calories,

and then I do a 20 minute bike ride, equivalent to 10km, burning around 180 - 200 calories.

Is there any problem there?

Another thing is that I still eat like anyone else would, not a care. What are the best kinds of food to eat when trying to lose fat/ lose weight.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I truly believe dietitians are underrated. I would suggest seeing one, even if it might cost money. Some supermarkets even have an in-house dietitian who could help you determine how to alter your meal plans, and then give a quick "tour" of the store so that you know where to buy those items.

1. I do not think there is any one good time to go the gym. If that fits your schedule, that is great! One thing, though, after a difficult workout it is best to eat a bit of protein and carbohydrates to allow your body to heal. Even if this seems counter-intuitive to lose weight (i.e. to be eating right after a workout late at night, it will allow you to continue your exercise regime with your body not breaking down over time).
2. I see no problem with your workout! It works out both your upper body and lower body, burns a lot of calories, and it does not cause too much joint-pounding that could be the case with long-distance running, especially for heavier runners who are trying to lose weight.
3. In terms of food, I advocate the best way to lose weight is to not go on any crash diet, and simply make small substitutions that do not rob you the pleasure and joy of eating delicious foods! Here are examples of (small) alterations to my diet that caused me to lose about 15 lbs of fat (in high school and NEVER GAINED BACK in the past eight years). I targeted my weak areas, which were soft drinks, sugar (especially milk chocolate), too much white pasta, and eating meals without having a small serving of fruits and vegetables:

   - Soft drinks --> Bubbled water with lemon and lime squeezed in.
   - Processed white grains --> Multigrain pasta, bagels, crackers, breads.
   - Red meats --> Lean chicken, turkey, and fish.
   - Milk chocolate --> Dark chocolate (If you have a sweet tooth like me, dark chocolate will fill you up faster. Sometimes I put peanut butter between pieces of Dark Chocolate like a Reeses Pieces or eat it with raspberries. Dark chocolate has a lot of iron, which we need to avoid anemia, and is shown to be better for the heart).
   - Eat a small serving of fruit or vegetables before meals. It will provide you with vitamins and fiber so you will feel full faster before you devour a heavy meal only to realize you ate too much too fast! It truly works for me.

When we see people lose weight (and keep it off) it is because of small changes without holding hostage their pleasure, energy, and health. Nobody has the will power to abide by some an austere, tasteless, Zen-like meal plan for very long, especially if it robs them of nutrients. A dietitian could help pinpoint your weaknesses if you were to show him or her a two-week long "food diary" of everything you eat and drink. Those weak areas can be targeted with healthier substitutions that are just as delicious, especially once you grow accustomed to them!

Comment: So true, many people don't know how to cook. When on a diet they switch from processed foods to idealess, boring food.

Answer (score 0):

It is far easier to make wiser eating choices than to exercise off poor choices. Your 50 minute workout barely covers the few minutes it takes to eat a Big Mac (not that I'm saying you eat Big Macs).

By eating quantities of foods delivering a low [Glycemic load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycemic_load), it is quite easy to take in less calories in a day and not feel hungry or feel like you're too restricted in food choices. You also get the benefits touted by lower carb diets such as reduced fat storage, reduced risk of cardiovascular disease and diabetes.

The main problem with working out that time is that you may simply run out of time to do it, or simply be too tired. Maintaining that workout every day just to lose a pound a week will be tough on the will-power.